# Is there a standard approach for searching a document for words in a list?

Tags: java, full-text-search

I'm working on an application that needs to search documents for all occurrences of words or phrases from a provided list. This is fairly easy to do by just walking a pointer through the document but this method does not scale.  As the document or dictionary get larger the search time increases proportionally eventually becoming unacceptable.   We have experimented with various approaches to reduce the scaling penalty.  On such approach is building an  index layer for the dictionary.  This is our current best strategy but I'm wondering if there is something better and/or easier.

I'm sure this problem has been solved innumerable times.  Is there an approach that has been shown to be optimal or at least close to optimal?

Comment: Use regular expressions

Comment: Lawrence, Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately regx comes with a lot of other problems.  Imagine a word list with 10,000 entries.  Not only is creating a regex for each entry a big pain but, at least with Java, the memory usage is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having performance issues you probably want to start looking at projects specifically meant to deal with full text searching like Apache Solr.

Solr allows you to feed it documents with which it builds an index to make searches for relevant keywords and phrases extremely fast.

Comment: Thanks tiguy,  We tried Solr and it works well.  Since we have what is essentially a special case we were able to use the Solr indexing approach for our search and get better performance.  But we still wonder if there is a standard indexing or other approach for this problem.